# Reference Request: GI Completeness of Directed, Bipartite, Colored Graphs

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, graph-isomorphism, directed-graphs

I have a proof of various gadgets by which I can show that directed, bipartite, vertex colored graphs are graph isomorphism complete. However, I'd rather just cite the result. Can someone give a reference? Thanks!

Comment: Write an answer to this question, and then cite Math StackExchange? :)

Comment: Have you checked the references listed [on the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem#GI-complete_classes_of_graphs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a reference with it. Just updating in case anyone else has the question in the future.

Zemlyachenko, V. N., Korneenko, N. M., & Tyshkevich, R. I. (1985). Graph isomorphism problem. Journal of Soviet Mathematics, 29(4), 1426–1481. doi:10.1007/bf02104746

This reference can be found on sci hub: https://sci-hub.tw/10.1007/bf02104746

Page 1469 in section 15 on equivalent isomorphism problems.